# Class questions regarding methods

Tags: python, class, arguments

Here's the classes that I do not understand:

```
class Person():
  def __init__(self,name,age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  def introduceSelf(self):
    print("Hi, My name is" + self.name +"and i am " + self.age + "years old")


class Police(Person):
  def arrest(self, toArrest):
      print("you are arrested," + toArrest)


Jenny = Police("Jenny",20)
Micheal = Person("Micheal",72)

Jenny.arrest("Micheal")
```

There are two arguments in `__init__` method and I had to define the variables
as `self.name = name` and `self.age = age`.
But in the `arrest` method, it still works even though I didn't mention `self.`.

As far as I understood, I thought I had to connect any variables (or arguments) in a method with `self.`. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: `toArrest` isn't an *attribute* of the `Police` instance, just an argument to the method. You only need to use `self.` when referring to attributes, including methods. Also I would suggest changing the method to expect a `Person` rather than a `str` of their name, so that it's `Jenny.arrest(Micheal)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> But in the arrest method, it still works even though I didn't mention self..

yes the instance is unused in *arrest*, so it can be a static method, anyway it is not mandatory to use the instance in a non static method

but if you want to indicate who arrests you will use *self* :

```
def arrest(self, toArrest):
   print(self.name + " arrests " + toArrest)
```

---

Can we suppose *toArrest* is also a *Person* ? in that case :

```
def arrest(self, toArrest):
   print(self.name + " arrests " + toArrest.name)
```